# Does using JSON object as a value have an effect for the performance of the speed of the database?

Tags: database, redis, nosql, key-value

I am trying to build a authentication system using redis . Emails are the keys other vales as hashed passwords , uuid are stored as a JSON object . That JSON object is the value of the key value pair (key is email). Redis is a very fast key-value store out there. So is there any effect to the performance of redis or any other disadvantage if I use JSON to store data ?

I am a beginner here . So I would be much thankful to you if you could provide some detailed answer 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No impact/performance difference compared to storing a similar-size string, Redis will store it as a string. **Redis won't know it is a JSON string** you are storing. See https://redis.io/topics/data-types.

This is assuming you are deserializing/serializing on the client app.

Consider the module [RedisJSON](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/) if you need more advanced capabilities than just storing JSON objects as serialized strings. Or use another data type, like *Hash*, to get field-level access.